# Storing data in a collection

Tags: java, collections

I have one requirement that is I have to store the employee data in in java collection

```
EmpId  EmpName EmpSalary
101     xxxxx    80000
101     yyyyy    40000
101     ddddd    60000 
101     zzzzz    80000
```

As shown above that `EmpId` is of `int` type and `EmpName` is of `String` type and `EmpSalary` is again of `int` type.

I was planning to store them in a Java collection, which might be generic. I have  a pojo with me having the three fields and their setters and getters.

Which java collection will be best suited for this requirement?

In my case ID field is not unique

Comment: Take a look at [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).. You need this..

Comment: Are you having multiple Employees with same EmpId?? HowCome?

Comment: @Rohit there is no primary key concept in this..!!

Comment: Ok, then in that case, you cannot use a `Map`.. You can better work with ArrayList..

Comment: @RohitJain can you please show it in the post so that understanding could be clear,Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1726942.. Check my post.. I have added an example on how you do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have unique value for EmpId, you can use ArrayList.: -

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    String Name;
    double salary;
}
```

Then have an `ArrayList<Employee>` and add your `POJO` instances to it..

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

empList.add(new Employee(1001, "rohit", 542345));
empList.add(new Employee(1001, "abc", 542345));
empList.add(new Employee(1001, "asf", 542345));
```

But, while retrieving Employees, you need to compare on more than one value.. So, you can override a `equals()` method in your `Employee POJO`.. then you can compare two `Employees` using `e1.equals(e2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Map<Integer, EmployeePojo>`, with the `EmpId` field the key, and the POJO as the value. **assuming the key values are unique**.  If it is, using a Map will give you excellent access time.

A more complete snippet, assuming your POJO is called `Employee`:

```
Map<Integer, Employee> employeeLookup = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
employeeLookup.put(employee1.getEmpId(), employee1);
employeeLookup.put(employee2.getEmpId(), employee2);
```

and to get an employee by id

```
Employee employee = employeeLookup.get(someId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an ideal situation for a HashMap. Use either the employee name or id as the key and the POJO as the value.

Comment: please check my latest post ,and also please post the code that will make understanding more clear

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new class, it would have 3 field variables that will contain the data.
then you can create an ArrayList of that new class you made.
In the class you can make getter and setters to maintain the data

Comment: please check my latest post ,and also please post the code that will make understanding more clear